# Format painter through Word interop

Tags: ms-word, interop

I want to implement some complex formatting using Word interop. It would be easy if I could copy the formatting from one range and then use the format painter to apply it to another range.

Is such a thing possible through the Word interop libraries?

Visual Studio 2008/Word 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/3f905707-b6d8-453d-9807-c7a9f8e9edae/

> The best you can do for "quick and dirty" (as opposed to working through the attributes, one-by-one) is to use the Selection.CopyFormat / Selection.PasteFormat methods of the Word object model. These emulate the Format Painter (paint brush) tool in the Word UI; for details look them up in the Help. Play around with that a bit and see if it gives you what you're after. If you need both paragraph and character-level attributes, copy the paragraph formatting first, then the character formatting.